# Vaadin calendar?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm reading the vaadin7 book to create a calendar to create some events. I created but I dont know how to create listener to when I click in some cells open a window and add the event.

How to do this ?

obs: In some foruns some users indicate to use Calendar add-on. This add-on is more simple ?

Comment: The calendar add-on is the same as the built in calendar now. In the past it was a add-on, now it's integrated into the core. We did try to use the calendar in one of our projects, but due to the whole thing missing serious documentation and also having restrictions on 30minutes units we now use our own calendar, simply based on a table.

Comment: @AndréSchild very nice...Are you have an example that you can show me ? thanks.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is our code to show a calendar based on a Grid.
This gives you a idea how this could be implemented.

```
package com.aarboard.reservation.reservations;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.BaseTheme;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class AarCalendar extends GridLayout
{
private final static Log _log= LogFactory.getLog(AarCalendar.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private LocalDate   _startDate;
private LocalDate   _endDate;

private LocalDate   _minDate= null;
private LocalDate   _maxDate= null;

private final DateTimeFormatter _dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
private final DateTimeFormatter _dateFormatterSmall = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d.MMM");
private final String[]    _weekDays= {"Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"};
private HashMap<String, Products1JO>   _boats= new HashMap<String, Products1JO>();
private HashMap<String, DayEntry>    _calEntries;

private AddressJO   _user;
private boolean _isAdminUser;

public AarCalendar(AddressJO user, boolean isAdminUser)
{
    _user= user;
    _isAdminUser= isAdminUser;
    setColumns(7);
    setRows(4);
    Products1ManagerDao p1Dao= new Products1ManagerDao();
    ContextSettings cSettings= ContextSettings.instance();
    p1Dao.setDataSource(cSettings.getDataSource());
    List<Products1JO> boats= p1Dao.getAllEntries();

    for (Products1JO boat : boats)
    {
        _boats.put(boat.getPrimaryKey(), boat);
    }

    addStyleName("calendarlayout");
    setRowExpandRatio(1, 10);
    setRowExpandRatio(2, 10);
    setRowExpandRatio(3, 10);
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        setColumnExpandRatio(i, 10);
        Label lbl= new Label(_weekDays[i]);
        lbl.setSizeUndefined();
        lbl.addStyleName("CalendarHeader");
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Button previousWeek= new Button();
            ThemeResource resource = new ThemeResource("img/btn_lt1.gif");
            previousWeek.setIcon(resource);
            previousWeek.setDescription("Eine Woche zurück");
            previousWeek.addStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
            HorizontalLayout hl= new HorizontalLayout();
            hl.setMargin(false);
            hl.setSpacing(false);
            hl.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            hl.addComponent(previousWeek);
            hl.addComponent(lbl);
            hl.setExpandRatio(lbl, 1);
            hl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
            addComponent(hl, i, 0);
            previousWeek.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event)
                    {
                        if (_minDate == null || _minDate.isBefore(_startDate))
                        {
                            LocalDate newStartDate= _startDate.minusDays(7);
                            if (_minDate != null && _minDate.isAfter(newStartDate))
                            {
                                newStartDate= _minDate;
                            }
                            loadCalendarForDate(newStartDate);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Notification.show("Am frühesten möglichen Termin", Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
        else if (i == 6)
        {
            Button nextWeek= new Button();
            ThemeResource resource = new ThemeResource("img/btn_rt1.gif");
            nextWeek.setIcon(resource);
            nextWeek.setDescription("Eine Woche vorwärts");
            nextWeek.addStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
            HorizontalLayout hl= new HorizontalLayout();
            hl.setMargin(false);
            hl.setSpacing(false);
            hl.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            hl.addComponent(lbl);
            hl.addComponent(nextWeek);
            hl.setExpandRatio(lbl, 1);
            hl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
            addComponent(hl, i, 0);
            nextWeek.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event)
                    {
                        if (_maxDate == null || _maxDate.isAfter(_startDate.plusDays(21)))
                        {
                            LocalDate newEndDate= _startDate.plusDays(7);
                            if (_maxDate != null && newEndDate.isAfter(_maxDate))
                            {
                                newEndDate= _maxDate;
                            }
                            loadCalendarForDate(newEndDate);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Notification.show("Am spätesten möglichen Termin", Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            addComponent(lbl, i, 0);
            setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        }
    }
}

public void loadCalendarForDate(LocalDate startDate)
{
    int euDOW= startDate.getDayOfWeek();
    if (euDOW == 0)
    {
        euDOW= 7;
    }
    else
    {
        euDOW= euDOW-1;
    }
    if (_minDate == null)
    {
        _startDate= startDate.minusDays(euDOW);
    }
    else
    {
        LocalDate sDate= startDate.minusDays(euDOW);
        if (sDate.isBefore(_minDate))
        {
            _startDate= startDate;
        }
        else
        {
            _startDate= sDate;
        }
    }
    _calEntries= new HashMap<String, DayEntry>();
    int nRows= getRows();
    int nCols= getColumns();
    for (int row= 1; row <= nRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col= 0; col <= nCols; col++)
        {
            removeComponent(col, row);
        }
    }

    int dayOfWeek= _startDate.getDayOfWeek();
    if (dayOfWeek == 0)
    {
        dayOfWeek= 7;
    }
    else
    {
        dayOfWeek= dayOfWeek-1;
    }
    int maxDaysToDisplay= 21;
    if (_maxDate != null && _maxDate.isBefore(_startDate.plusDays(maxDaysToDisplay)))
    {
        maxDaysToDisplay= maxDaysToDisplay; // TODO Complete end calculation
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < (maxDaysToDisplay-dayOfWeek); i++)
    {
        int colNum= (i+dayOfWeek)  % 7;
        int row= ((i+dayOfWeek) / 7)+1;
        LocalDate ld2= _startDate.plusDays(i);
        _endDate= ld2;
        DayEntry de= new DayEntry(ld2);
        _calEntries.put(ld2.toString(_dateFormatter), de);
        if (colNum == 6)
        {
            de.addStyleName("dayEntryLastCol");
        }
        if (row == 3)
        {
            de.addStyleName("dayEntryLastRow");
        }
        addComponent(de, colNum, row);
    }

    Duration dur= new Duration(_startDate.toDate().getTime(), _endDate.toDate().getTime());
    long nDays= dur.getStandardDays();
    for (int i = 0; i <= nDays; i++) 
    {
        createEventsForDay(_startDate.plusDays(i));
    }
}

void createEventsForDay(LocalDate day) 
{
    ContextSettings cSettings= ContextSettings.instance();
    Events1ManagerDao e1Dao= new Events1ManagerDao();
    e1Dao.setDataSource(cSettings.getDataSource());
    List<Events1JO> events= e1Dao.getAllEntriesForDay(day.toDate());
    ArrayList<ReservationJO> reservations= new ArrayList<ReservationJO>();
    for (Events1JO ev : events)
    {
        reservations.add(new ReservationJO(ev));
    }

    for (ReservationJO res : reservations)
    {
        addEvent(res, false);

    }
    showEntries(day);
}

public class DayEntry extends VerticalLayout
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private HashMap<String, VerticalLayout>    _vl= new HashMap<String, VerticalLayout>(); // Hashmap with boatID + VerticalLayouts as container
    private HashMap<String, List<ReservationJO>> _entries= new HashMap<String, List<ReservationJO>>();
    private LocalDate   _currentDay;

    public DayEntry(LocalDate ld)
    {
        setMargin(true);
        _currentDay= ld;
        addStyleName("dayEntry");
        setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        String caption= ld.toString(_dateFormatter);
        setDescription(caption);
        HorizontalLayout hl= new HorizontalLayout();
        hl.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        addComponent(hl);
        Label lbl= new Label(ld.toString(_dateFormatterSmall));
        lbl.setSizeUndefined();
        hl.addComponent(lbl);
        hl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        HorizontalLayout hl2= new HorizontalLayout();
        addComponent(hl2);
        setExpandRatio(hl2, 10);
        hl2.setSizeFull();
        for (Products1JO boat : _boats.values())
        {
            List<ReservationJO> resList= new ArrayList<ReservationJO>();
            _entries.put(boat.getPrimaryKey(), resList);
            VerticalLayout vl= new VerticalLayout();
            hl2.addComponent(vl);
            vl.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            _vl.put(boat.getPrimaryKey(), vl);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a entry for this day (It does not automatically update the display
     * Use showEntries for this
     * 
     * @param newEntry 
     */
    public void addEntry(ReservationJO newEntry)
    {
        List<ReservationJO> list= _entries.get(newEntry.getBoatID());
        list.add(newEntry);
    }

    public void removeEntry(ReservationJO newEntry)
    {
        List<ReservationJO> list= _entries.get(newEntry.getBoatID());
        list.remove(newEntry);
    }

    public void showEntries()
    {
        for (VerticalLayout vl : _vl.values())
        {
            vl.removeAllComponents();
        }
        boolean isFirst= true;
        for (String id : _vl.keySet())
        {
            VerticalLayout vl= _vl.get(id);
            Products1JO boat= _boats.get(id);
            String boatCaption= boat.getTitle().get("DE");
            List<ReservationJO> list= _entries.get(id);
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ReservationJO>()
                {
                    public int compare(ReservationJO obj1, ReservationJO obj2)
                    {
                        return obj1.getStartTime() - obj2.getStartTime();
                    }
                });

            int currentHour= StartEndTimeSelector.FIRST_HOUR;
            for (ReservationJO res : list)
            {
                int startTime= res.getStartTime();
                if (startTime > currentHour)
                {
                    // First reservation does not start on first possible hour
                    FreeEntry lbl= new FreeEntry("Frei", boat.getPrimaryKey(), currentHour, startTime);
                    lbl.setData(res);
                    lbl.setDescription(boatCaption);
                    lbl.setSizeFull();
                    lbl.addStyleName( BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
                    lbl.addStyleName("FreeTime");
                    if (!isFirst)
                    {
                        lbl.addStyleName("FreeTimeLeftBorder");
                    }
                    vl.addComponent(lbl);
                    vl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                    vl.setExpandRatio(lbl, startTime - currentHour);
                    lbl.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event)
                            {
                                ReservationJO res= new ReservationJO();
                                FreeEntry entry= (FreeEntry)(event.getButton());
                                res.setStartEndDate(_currentDay, entry.getStartTime(), entry.getEndTime()); // Default 1 hour
                                res.setBoatID(entry.getBoatID());
                                ReservationDetailsWindow popup= new ReservationDetailsWindow(AarCalendar.this, res, false, false, _isAdminUser);
                                getUI().addWindow(popup);
                            }
                        });    
                }
                currentHour= res.getEndTime();
                BookedEntry lbl= new BookedEntry(startTime+":00-"+currentHour+":00", boatCaption, res);
                lbl.addStyleName( BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
                if (!isFirst)
                {
                    lbl.addStyleName("ReservedTimeLeftBorder");
                }
                lbl.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

                vl.addComponent(lbl);
                vl.setExpandRatio(lbl, currentHour-startTime);
                vl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
            }
            if (currentHour < StartEndTimeSelector.LAST_HOUR)
            {
                FreeEntry lbl= new FreeEntry("Frei", boat.getPrimaryKey(), currentHour, StartEndTimeSelector.LAST_HOUR);
                lbl.setDescription(boatCaption);
                lbl.addStyleName( BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
                lbl.addStyleName("FreeTime");
                if (!isFirst)
                {
                    lbl.addStyleName("FreeTimeLeftBorder");
                }
                lbl.setSizeFull();
                vl.addComponent(lbl);
                vl.setExpandRatio(lbl, StartEndTimeSelector.LAST_HOUR - currentHour);
                vl.setComponentAlignment(lbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                lbl.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event)
                        {
                            ReservationJO res= new ReservationJO();
                            FreeEntry entry= (FreeEntry)(event.getButton());
                            res.setStartEndDate(_currentDay, entry.getStartTime(), entry.getEndTime()); // Default 1 hour
                            res.setBoatID(entry.getBoatID());
                            ReservationDetailsWindow popup= new ReservationDetailsWindow(AarCalendar.this, res, false, false, _isAdminUser);
                            getUI().addWindow(popup);
                        }
                    });    
            }
            isFirst= false;
        }
    }

}

public LocalDate getStartDate()
{
    return _startDate;
}

public void addEvent(ReservationJO newEntry, boolean refreshView)
{
    Date startDate= newEntry.getStartDate();
    LocalDate lstartDate= new LocalDate(startDate);
    DayEntry de= _calEntries.get(lstartDate.toString(_dateFormatter));
    if (de != null)
    {
        de.addEntry(newEntry);
        if (refreshView)
        {
            de.showEntries();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _log.fatal("No such entry found in calendar: "+lstartDate);
    }
}

public void removeEvent(ReservationJO oldEntry, boolean refreshView)
{
    Date startDate= oldEntry.getStartDate();
    LocalDate lstartDate= new LocalDate(startDate);
    DayEntry de= _calEntries.get(lstartDate.toString(_dateFormatter));
    if (de != null)
    {
        de.removeEntry(oldEntry);
        if (refreshView)
        {
            de.showEntries();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _log.fatal("No such entry found in calendar: "+lstartDate);
    }
}

public void showEntries(LocalDate day)
{
    DayEntry de= _calEntries.get(day.toString(_dateFormatter));
    if (de != null)
    {
        de.showEntries();
    }
    else
    {
        _log.fatal("No such entry found in calendar: "+day);
    }
}
public LocalDate getEndDate()
{
    return _endDate;
}

protected class FreeEntry extends Button
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int _startTime;
    private int _endTime;
    private String _boatID;

    public FreeEntry(String caption, String boatID, int startTime, int endTime)
    {
        super(caption);
        _startTime = startTime;
        _endTime = endTime;
        _boatID = boatID;
    }

    public String getBoatID()
    {
        return _boatID;
    }

    public int getEndTime()
    {
        return _endTime;
    }

    public int getStartTime()
    {
        return _startTime;
    }
}

protected class BookedEntry extends Button
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BookedEntry(String caption, String boatCaption, ReservationJO reservation)
    {
        super(caption);
        setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

        final ReservationJO myReservation= reservation;

        String myAdrID= reservation != null ? reservation.getAddressID() : null;
        boolean isOwn= AarCalendar.this._user.getPrimaryKey().equals(myAdrID);
        if (isOwn)
        {
            setDescription(boatCaption+" "+AarCalendar.this._user.getAddressname());
        }
        else
        {
            if (_isAdminUser)
            {
                ContextSettings cSettings= ContextSettings.instance();
                AddressManagerDao aDao= new AddressManagerDao();
                aDao.setDataSource(cSettings.getDataSource());
                AddressJO address= aDao.getEntry(reservation.getAddressID());
                setDescription(boatCaption+" "+address.getAddressname());
            }
            else
            {
                setDescription(boatCaption);
            }
        }
        addStyleName("ReservationEntry");
        addClickListener(new ClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
                {
                    boolean allowDelete= true;
                    allowDelete= _isAdminUser || (myReservation.getAddressID().equals(AarCalendar.this._user.getPrimaryKey()) && !myReservation.isMailSent());
                    ReservationDetailsWindow popup= new ReservationDetailsWindow(AarCalendar.this, myReservation, true, allowDelete, _isAdminUser);
                    getUI().addWindow(popup);
                }
            });
    }
}

public void setMinDate(LocalDate minDate)
{
    _minDate= minDate;
}

public void setMaxDate(LocalDate maxDate)
{
    _maxDate= maxDate;
}
}
```